SNOWFLAKE COPY INTO command is atomic
Is the Snowflake COPY command atomic, meaning does it operate within a single transaction similar like DML operations?
Syntax:
COPY INTO <table>
COPY INTO <location>

It depends on how you set the ON_ERROR parameter. If you set it to ABORT_STATEMENT then it would be atomic in the sense that it will rollback. SKIP_FILE is atomic for each file, but not the overall COPY command (assuming there is more than one file)
